# Two step CSS transition reverse does not work

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a menu that slides in from the left and then vertically slides open, and closes by reversing those steps, sliding closed and then sliding away to the left.

I'm trying to use css transitions for this. I can get the menu to appear with a two step transition, but reversing doesn't work. According to other questions, reversing the steps should work, but for my specific case it does not. What is happening here?

Css

```
.menu-slide {
            position: absolute;
            width: 220px;
            top: 90px;                
            color: #fff;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
            overflow: hidden;
}
.open {
            transition: left 1s, max-height 1.5s 1s;  
            left: 55px !important;
            opacity: .80;
            max-height: 600px !important;
}

.closed {

           transition: max-height 1.5s, left 1s 1s;    
           left: -255px !important;
           opacity: 0;
           max-height: 20px !important;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/_erin_/u5z5yrmy/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have set `opacity: 0;` on `.closed` set it to `.80`:

```
.closed {           
   transition: max-height 1.5s, left 1s 1s;    
   left: -255px !important;
   opacity: .80;
   max-height: 20px !important;
}
```

**[Your fiddle updated.](https://jsfiddle.net/u5z5yrmy/5/)**

Comment: Thank you! I was going to add opacity to the transition, that's why it was even there.